# Como hacer un efecto palanca en Javascript(sin jQuery)

Tags: javascript

Tengo una consulta.

Sucede que quiero formar una "X" con Javascript: dándole clic a un div llama a una función que interactua al css y cambia la posición de otros div's mas pequeños y forman una "X". Bueno, eso si lo he podido hacer. Mi problema es que quiero que al darle clic al mismo div, quiero que los elementos regresen a su forma original (algo así como un efecto palanca) pero no he podido lograrlo.

Ya se que existe jQuery y también se puede hacer con CSS pero la verdad quiero hacerlo netamente con un código que yo mismo haga para así poder aprender y no solo usar librerías. Ademas, intentando solucionar esto me tope con otro tema... ¿Por qué Javascript solo encuentra a los elementos si solo los llamo por el ID?, intente llamarlos por el class pero no sucede nada, como si no los reconociera. Gracias de ante mano a los que puedan ayudarme.

```js
 function exis(){
               var elementoDiv1 = document.getElementById('primera-linea');
               var elementoDiv2 = document.getElementById('segunda-linea');
               
               elementoDiv1.style.right="5px";
               elementoDiv2.style.top="5px";
               elementoDiv1.style.transform="rotate(-30deg)";
               elementoDiv2.style.transform="rotate(30deg)";
            
           }
```

```css
        #Conten{
               width: 65px;
               height: 65px;
               padding-top: 10px;
               background-color: blueviolet;
           }
           #Conten div{
               width: 60px;
               height: 5px;
               margin-bottom: 5px;
               border-radius: 3px;
           }
           #BTN:checked ~ #Conten div{
               background-color: green;
           }
           #primera-linea {
               /*transform: rotate(-30deg);*/
               transform-origin: right;
               background-color: brown;
               /*top: 10px;*/
               /*right: 5px;*/
               transition: transform 0.5s;
               position: relative;
           }
           #segunda-linea{
               position: relative;
               /*top: 5px;*/
               /*transform: rotate(30deg);*/
               transform-origin: center;
               transition: transform 0.5s;
               background-color: red;
           }
           #tercera-linea{
               display: none;
               background-color: dimgrey;
               position: relative;
               top: 0px;
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
    <body>
      <!--<div id="contenedor">
       <input type="checkbox" id="BTN">
      <label for="BTN"> CLICK</label>-->
       <div id="Conten"  onclick="exis()" >
          <div id="primera-linea"></div>
          <div id="segunda-linea"></div>
          <div id="tercera-linea"></div> 
       </div>
      <!-- </div>-->
          
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes de poner el código que llevas, así no te responderán.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia , es la primera ves que hago una consulta por aquí

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes poner una variable bandera que vea el estado actual del click, si la animación ya se hizo de una forma que se haga de la otra y viceversa.

```js
 var bandera = false
 function exis(){
        var elementoDiv1 = document.getElementById('primera-linea');
        var elementoDiv2 = document.getElementById('segunda-linea');
        if (!bandera){
               elementoDiv1.style.right="5px";
               elementoDiv2.style.top="5px";
               elementoDiv1.style.transform="rotate(-30deg)";
               elementoDiv2.style.transform="rotate(30deg)";
               bandera = true;
         } else{
               elementoDiv1.style.right="0px";
               elementoDiv2.style.top="0px";
               elementoDiv1.style.transform="rotate(0deg)";
               elementoDiv2.style.transform="rotate(0deg)";
               bandera = false;
         } 
 }
```

```css
       #Conten{
               width: 65px;
               height: 65px;
               padding-top: 10px;
               background-color: blueviolet;
           }
           #Conten div{
               width: 60px;
               height: 5px;
               margin-bottom: 5px;
               border-radius: 3px;
           }
           #BTN:checked ~ #Conten div{
               background-color: green;
           }
           #primera-linea {
               /*transform: rotate(-30deg);*/
               transform-origin: right;
               background-color: brown;
               /*top: 10px;*/
               /*right: 5px;*/
               transition: transform 0.5s;
               position: relative;
           }
           #segunda-linea{
               position: relative;
               /*top: 5px;*/
               /*transform: rotate(30deg);*/
               transform-origin: center;
               transition: transform 0.5s;
               background-color: red;
           }
           #tercera-linea{
               display: none;
               background-color: dimgrey;
               position: relative;
               top: 0px;
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
    <body>
       <div id="Conten"  onclick="exis()" >
          <div id="primera-linea"></div>
          <div id="segunda-linea"></div>
          <div id="tercera-linea"></div> 
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Respecto al llamado por clase, cuando llamas por medio de la clases hay más de un resultado posible, a diferencia del `id` que debe ser único e irrepetible. Por lo tanto el resultado de obtenerlo por medio de la `clase` es un `array`.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
    x[0].innerHTML = "hola";
    x[1].innerHTML = "mundo";
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  Primer div con class="example".
</div>

<div class="example">
  Segundo div con class="example".
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta si me sirvió, es la primera ves que uso esta plataforma  asi que no se que hacer (darte un like o algo asi ) de todos modos te estoy muy agradecido

Comment: Que bien que te haya servido. Puedes darte el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) inicial para ver cómo funciona el sitio. Y [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) puedes ver acerca de las respuestas aceptadas y su utilidad.